# How to infer the types of all the parameters of a function using java-parser and java-symbol-solver?

Tags: java, parsing, binding, javaparser

Suppose I have the following `Class A` in `pkg1` and a `Class B` in `pkg2` and function `calculate()` is defined in `pkg2` `class B` as follows:

```
B.calculate(A a1, A a2);
```

I want to identify the the type of parameters `a1` and `a2`. For instance, here it will be `pkg1.A` and `pkg1.A` as `class A` belongs to `pkg1`.

My main concern is, I do not want to build the project, I want to do static analysis(I have all the source files).

I know a way to infer the the parameter types using Eclipse JDT but how do I do it using javaparser(https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) and javasymbolsolver(https://github.com/javaparser/javasymbolsolver).

In Eclipse JDT, i have just set the source files' path in the parser environment and it worked. But in javasymbolsolver, even after I add the source files in the typesolver, it is not working.

```
CombinedTypeSolver combinedTypeSolver = new CombinedTypeSolver();
combinedTypeSolver.add(new JavaParserTypeSolver("path to the sourcefiles"));
JavaParserFacade j=JavaParserFacade.get(combinedTypeSolver);
SymbolReference<MethodDeclaration> ref = j.solve((MethodCallExpr) n);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify also the path to the dependencies. The CombinedTypeSolver should know where to find not only the source files but also all the jars.

Something like this should work:

> combinedTypeSolver.add(new JarTypeSolver(new File("libs/mylib.jar")));

Source: I am the mantainer of JavaSymbolSolver

Comment: I do not have the jars of the project, all i have is the source code(I do not intend to build the project, since i have to do this for multiple projects).Is'nt there a work around in javasymbolsolver?   I did something like this in EclipseJDT   `astParser.setEnvironment("pathTojreLib", "pathToSourceFiles", new String[] { "UTF-8"}, true);`

Comment: No: I mean, it can calculate all the types which do not involve the libraries. But if I class X extend a class from the library there is no possible workaround for that

Comment: So here if, pkg1.A does not involve libraries and it does not extend any class from library, it should work right?

Comment: Yes, but you should at least configure it to use the classes from the JRE (the standard library). To do that you need to add a ReflectionTypeSolver.